# The result of Mybatis contains uppercase and lowercase

Tags: jakarta-ee, mybatis, uppercase, lowercase

This is my interface method:

```
HashMap<String,Object> getUserById(int id);
```

and this is my XML method:

```
<select id="getUserById" parameterType="int" resultType="hashmap" >  
        select * from users where user_id = #{user_id}
    </select>
```

then I use the Junit to test it,this is my Junit case:

```
@Test
    public void testGetUsers() 
    {
            HashMap<String,Object> maps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            int id = 5;
        maps = mapper.getUserById(id);
        System.out.println(maps);
        Assert.assertNotNull(maps);
    }
```

then I got the result like this:

```
{DEPARTMENT_ID=1, phone=3423456, NAME=张飞, USER_ID=5, department_id=1, password=1111, PHONE=3423456, username=zhangfei, email=zhangfei@qq.com, MOBILE=12345678963, name=张飞, user_id=5, USERNAME=zhangfei, EMAIL=zhangfei@qq.com, PASSWORD=1111, mobile=12345678963}
```

as you see,the result contains uppercase and lowercase,but I dosen't want to the uppercase,how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enforce the lowercase in the query

```
select MY_COLUMN as from my_column ...
```

If that doesn't work, take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11732674/980472).