# mybatis select users by user ids

Tags: java, mybatis

I have an user model like this:

```
class User { 
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String password;
}
```

Now I am trying to get some users by user ids;

The result I want is a hashMap like this:

key id 10001 value user1

key id 10002 value user2

and then I can select the user by id and set to the topic.

```
topic.setUser(resultMap.get(id));
```

my config file:

```
<select id="getUsers"  >
   select id, name, password from user
   where id in
   <foreach item="id" index="index" collection="list"   open="("  separator="," close=")">
      #{id}  
   </foreach>
</select>
```

Now the question is How to return a map and the key is id and value is the user object

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at `@MapKey` annotation

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913013/return-hashmap-in-mybatis-and-use-it-as-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc