# MyBatis query result in a HashMap?

Tags: java, sql, orm, mybatis

For the below query,

```
 SELECT 
     MSGS.MSGTYPE,
     count(*) as NOOFRECORDS 
 FROM 
     SCHEMA.MESSAGES MSGS
 GROUP BY 
     MSGS.MSGTYPE
```

What would be the equivalent in MyBatis mapper so that I can get a Result as a HashMap with MSGS.MSGTYPE as the key and NOOFRECORDS as the value ?

Comment: I got a good reference here so i guess i have my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913013/return-hashmap-in-mybatis-and-use-it-as-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<select id="selectAllCategories" resultType="hashmap">
 select id, name from categories  
</select>
```

and More details here

[Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913013/return-hashmap-in-mybatis-and-use-it-as-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)