# Retrieve values in map using MyBatis from join on two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

I'm trying to fetch values on joining two tables and getting those into a map, in MyBatis.

For example, two tables, "ABC" and "XYZ:
Table ABC columns: `id` and `code`
Table XYZ columns: `id`, `pid` and `relation_with_user`

Query being used:

```
select xyz.id as cId, xyz.relation_with_user as relationWithUser
from ABC abc left join XYZ xyz
on abc.id = xyz.pid where code = #{code}
```

The resultant map should be `Map(Integer, String)`.

I want to set the `id` of the XYZ table as key and `relation_with_user` as value in the map. How can I do that?

Comment: What's the < mapper > you have tried so far? Sounds like pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is described in option 2 of [this answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915144/7076047).