# how to map two result columns as key value to map

Tags: mybatis

mybatis will return a map that columnName is key,and columnValue as value.But the result map I want is that the key is the value of column 1, and the value is the 
 value of column 2.

I use this to map,and it did'n work,and throw TooManyResultsException.

```
<resultMap id="countMap" type="HashMap">
  <result property="key" column="column1"/>
  <result property="value" column="column2"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913013/ For my taste it seems a bit complicated (for something so simple)